# Default All Day Event to Check/Yes

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Thanks for the great help.  Another question.  How do I set my "All Day Event" field on the calendar to default to "Checked/Yes?"   If we can set the default on All Day Event to Yes, is there a way to hide the time fields (keep the date fields - just no time fields)?  I'd also like to hide the "Workspace" field as well (if possible).

Thank You

Dave M

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to run code on your server, I've run this from a console application and it worked like a charm:

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursite"))
{
  using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
  {
    SPList list = web.Lists["your list name"];
    SPContentType ct = list.ContentTypes["Event"];
    SPFieldLink fieldLink = ct.FieldLinks["fAllDayEvent"];
    Type type = typeof(SPFieldLink);
    PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty("Default", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    pi.SetValue(fieldLink, "1", null);
    ct.Update();
  }
}
```

Source: http://pholpar.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!2CD45589973F2849!131.entry

Only modification we had to make was the SPFieldLink, the examples uses `All Day Event`, our lists used `fAllDayEvent`.

The only other way I've seen work is to modify the list's CAML ([Example](http://ablog.apress.com/?p=1366)).

Oh, and we hid the Workspace field using Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideFields");

function fc(FieldName) {
   var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("!");

   for (var i=0;i < arr.length; i++ ) {
      if (arr[i].innerHTML.indexOf(FieldName) > 0) { return arr[i]; }
   }
}

function hideFields() {
   control = fc("Workspace");
   control.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";
}
</script>
```

Source: http://sharepointsherpa.com/2008/08/26/sharepoint-2007-hiding-fields-on-newformaspx-and-editformaspx-the-easy-way/