# How to disambiguate the Type.GetProperty method in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, reflection, powershell-2.0, overloading

I am trying to create a Powershell script that does what the C# code [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969857/988264) does.

When I get to the line

```
$type = ($fieldlink).GetType()
$propInfo = $type.GetProperty("Default", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic -bor [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance)
```

I'm getting an error

> Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "GetProperty" and the argument
>   count: "2".

How do I disambiguate and specify that I want the overload that takes a string and BindingFlags?

Comment: What type is `$fieldlink`?, you might be able to force one overload with as cast: `GetProperty("Default",([System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance) -as [System.Reflection.BindingFlags])`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `$fieldLink` is an [`SPFieldLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlink_members(v=office.14).aspx). Incorrect casting did turn out to be the problem, see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-bor` operator return result of underlying type (`[int]` in this case) rather then original enum type. So you have to cast result back to `[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]`, although I prefer to cast to enum type from string:

```powershell
$propInfo = $type.GetProperty("Default", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]'NonPublic, Instance')
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly, and taught me a couple things about enums in Powershell.